# Setting JPanel/JFrame background image, my 1st time

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm back with yet another really stupid question.  I read some other stackoverflow posts already, and tried to follow the advice, but to no avail.  I cannot get the JPanel background to change to an image!  I tried moving the image to my c:\, so it's not that.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Login code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class login implements ActionListener{


    JTextField gusername;
    JTextField gpassword;
    static String username;
    static String password;

    void logini() throws IOException {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Login");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300, 250);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);

        JPanel mainp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        window.add(mainp);



        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\bgd.png"));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
        mainp.add( picLabel );




        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        gusername = new JTextField();
        gusername.setText("Username");
        mainp.add(gusername, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        gpassword = new JTextField();
        gpassword.setText(" password ");
        mainp.add(gpassword, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        mainp.add(login, c);

        login.addActionListener(this);
        login.setActionCommand("ok");
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
            try {
                this.username = (gusername.getText());
                this.password = (gpassword.getText());
                System.out.println("0");

            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not preform function: 7424");

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at login.logini(login.java:34)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Escape the backslash in your path.**

A backslash is a special escape character in strings.  `\b` is a special character, not a backslash and a b.  To get a backslash, you need two of them `\\`.

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\bgd.png"));
```

I would suggest using `File.separatorChar` instead for platform-independence, but `C:` is hardly platform independent.

Comment: Another recommendation is to read in a string from your app, and use that instead of hard coding your location.  make sure wherever you move your program to, that you move the picture to as well or it won't work.

Comment: @Erick Robertson Now that the image is up, why doesn't my other components show up?

Comment: @TimothyO'Connell This is a separate question, but it probably has to do with not setting `GridBagConstraints` for the image when you add it.  So it's probably sitting on top of all of the other components and you can't see them.